# Neo4j LOAD CSV record processed sequence

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I've been using `LOAD CSV` for some time now with `neo4j` to `import` data but I think, not sure, I noticed that the `LOAD CSV` will start importing rows from the bottom of the `csv` file.

Or is it completely random?

I'm trying to create an `(org)-[:has_suborg]->(subOrg)` relationship while I'm processing each row but I want to make sure that the parent `orgs` are created first to avoid `exceptions/errors` when a sub is attempted to be related to a parent org and the parent org is not present yet.

If rows are processed from the top or the bottom I can then make sure that my `csv` records are already sorted the way I want them processed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the csv format?

Comment: Standard comma separated values like: id, org_name, website, parent_org_id, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV will be processed from top to bottom - in that order. What might be worth considering is doing a double load of your data.

First pass just CREATE/MERGE your org nodes. Second pass, MATCH the org nodes, then create the rest of the data.

Using this approach you will avoid any potential order issues, as well as dodging eager queries.

Comment: Yep great idea Lju, I actually ended up doing that by myself like a week ago and it worked really well, this "phased" approach to creating data. But thanks anyway for confirming the processing order (top to bottom), is there some kind of documentation that has this info anywhere? Could find anything, thanks!